# Windows MSVC SDK on Fuerte

Tags: windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking to use the Windows version of ROS Fuerte and wanted to know the status of the SDK. Looking at the Windows Install page for Fuerte, the "Msvc SDK" linked page doesn't seem to exist yet. So, I wanted to check and see if there was any time frame on when the SDK might be available (with installation similar to the Electric version)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32640/windows-msvc-sdk-on-fuerte/) by [Jon](https://answers.ros.org/users/1247/jon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2012-04-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is underway - currently working on the build environment still. Keep an eye on the web page - when it is ready, that link will appear.

Updates: some tutorials have been added.

- [Msvc SDK](http://www.ros.org/wiki/win_ros/Msvc%20SDK%20-%20Fuerte) : installing the ros sdk.
- [Msvc SDK Projects](http://www.ros.org/wiki/win_ros/Msvc%20SDK%20Projects%20-%20Fuerte) : demo and tutorial illustrating how to use the sdk to build visual express/studio projects.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2012-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jon](https://answers.ros.org/users/1247/jon/) on 2012-05-10**:
I set up the Msvc SDK for Fuerte as described on the webpage and found I needed to make one additional change to get things working. The addition to the directions was to add C:/Python27 to the PATH variable in C:\opt\ros\fuerte\x86\setup.bat. After the change roscore worked.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2012-05-15**:
Good catch - thanks. Updated the tutorial on roswiki.